# Ajax Call not working on android But working fine on ios Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, phonegap-plugins

**Edit:** Off course server side is fine because ajax is doing fine with IOS and browser => Cross origin request are allowed

---

I am developing a cordova mobile application. I build the app for android and ios but android app doest work and dnt send ajax request . Mean while Ios app works correctly. Here is my  config.xml .....

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.unitedway" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>fw3</name>
    <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Documents" />
    <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="WebSecurity" value="disable" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="io.phasr.cordova.plugin.itunesfilesharing" spec="https://github.com/christianjunk/cordova-plugin-itunesfilesharing" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
</widget>
```

Here is my android AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.unitedway" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

My ajax request code which returns status 404 .

So ajax request fail on android but is works fine on ios and browser.

Comment: Above code is fine, have you allowed from the server to which you want fire ajax. There is a concept Cross-Origin Resource Sharing , You have to allow to get request from your application to server from server side. for more fo through it https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: @Hassan try adding the following in config.XML for android platform - <allow-intent href="http://*/*" /> 
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" /> 
<allow-intent href="tel:*" /> 
<allow-intent href="sms:*" /> 
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" /> 
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />

Comment: @Gandhi I have read `<allow-intent href="*" />` Should do same as they all do

Comment: @AnantaPrasadLoda yes. See my edit (at top).. From server cross origin requests are allowed

Comment: This is from app, i am saying you have to allow cross origin in server side Mr @Sami

Comment: @Hassan But did you tried out once in the way as i suggested? Any error trace in console?

Comment: @Hassan: Can you try some ajax call with https://randomuser.me/documentation and copy all your code here. All the configuration as you show us above seem correct.

Comment: @Hassan I believe to make ajax calls. this setting is mandatory - <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" /> Try out once

Comment: Mr @AnantaPrasadLoda! What else to explain.  I told cross origin request is allowed from server side..  in java at server i have `httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` and it works quite fine

Comment: @Gandhi..  These things `<allow-intent href="http://*/*" /> ` etc had been already tried by him. Console says `404 not found`.

Comment: Could it be that the whitelist plugin is not (correctly) installed? This seems to be causing 404's. Have you tried removing and re-adding the Android platform? Does the plugin show up with `cordova plugin list`?

Comment: Yes. It is done several times.. Removed both plugin (whitelist) and platform (android).. added them again

Comment: @Sami Could you post your code in  github so that we can install and check out in actual device itself?

Comment: Yes @Gandhi, thanks a lot for so much attention. I am downloading/installing gihub client.. Will share the link soon

Comment: @Gandhi https://github.com/humblesami/androidajaxrequest

Comment: @Sami I downloaded your project, replaced your project source code  in my newly create project and replaced fileDel click function's ajax url to my local url and i m successfully able to make ajax calls. Infact i have placed an alert in success callback and i m getting alert too

Comment: @Gandhi Are you testing it in Android device.Please confirm

Comment: @HassanALi I tested on Android device(Motog 2nd gen) running android marshmallow. Cordova version - 6.2.0 Cordova android version 4.1.1

Comment: @HassanALi Check out this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Ajax_Test/ Have added the generated android platform folder too in this for your reference. Hope it helps

Comment: @Sami Check out this link - github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Ajax_Test Have added the generated android platform folder too in this for your reference. Hope it helps

Comment: @Gandhi Thanks let me check i will response you .

Comment: @HassanALi Keep me posted

Comment: @Sami Have posted the answer and glad it helped. Awaiting your bounty :) Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your project, replaced your project source code in my newly create project and replaced delete button click function's AJAX url call to my local URL and i m successfully able to make AJAX calls. In fact, i have placed an alert in success callback and i m getting alert too.

So by all means it has got nothing to do with coding. It could be a possible problem with Android platform creation in first place or it could be issue with cordova whitelist plugin installation.

Have posted the working codebase in [github](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Ajax_Test/) Have also included plugin and Android platform for your reference along with the codebase. Do make use of the same for further development. Hope it helps.

Comment: @HassanALi I m humbled. Glad it was helpful. Happy coding. Awaiting bounty :) cheers

Comment: @Sami Thanks Sami. Glad that i could help you guys. Wish we will meet up on some other issue soon. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

As of version 5 or so, cordova requires [whitelist plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/). Then `<access origin="*" />` (or any origin you pick) should work.

Comment: Please check my config.xml I had installed whitelist plugin and also had added this <access origin="*" />.But still it didnt work only on android.

Comment: I did not notice, as it was down the listing. For me it did the job. Do the requests reach the server at all? In my case they were not even sent by the device. But if whitelist is not the solution, I do not know what it would be.